# Given an object where the value is an array, what is the most efficient way to return the pair [key, array.length]?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a wordcloud in d3, which requires your data to be in the format of

```
{word : 'hello', size: 3}
```

However, my data is formatted as such:

```
{'hello': [[1,1,15], [2,4,17], [5,8,18]]}
```

Where the word itself is the key and the values are the dates in which I found this word. So what I need is a way to give .words() the object, but tell it that rather than using the actual value itself, to use the length of the value instead. Is there a function I can use to do this without having to loop through the data or change the data?

I found I could use `d3.entries(`wordlist`)` to get the format almost right:

```
{key: 'hello', value: [[1,1,15], [2,4,17], [5,8,18]]}
```

But I struggle with what's the right function to replace the dates with the length when sending it to .words(). I was reading up on the .map function but I don't think that's the right tool for the job.

If absolutely necessary I can manipulate the data before hand but I'd like to avoid it since there's a lot and I'm trying to avoid unnecessary computations or repeat data storage.

Comment: the way your data is formatted would give you a syntax error

Comment: Are you sure your data isn't `{'hello': [[1,1,15], [2,4,17], [5,8,18]]}`? ...otherwise it doesn't parse

Comment: Whoops, sorry, yes! It's an array of arrays. I've updated the original post to correct that syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `map` to get an array of name/length pairs:

```js
let obj = {
  'hello': [[1,1,15], [2,4,17], [5,8,18]],
  'goodby': [[1, 5, 17]],
  'hey': [[5, 8, 18], [6, 2, 15]]
}

let arr = Object.entries(obj)
          .map(([key, val]) => ({word: key, size: val.length}))
console.log(arr)
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Just tested it -- yes! this is perfect! I didn't quite understand how .map worked, but looking at your solution it seems so obvious. Thank you very much for this solution, you've saved me loads of time!